# Increment / Decrement in stored procedure T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with following fields:

```
ID , FirstName , LastName , Count , Amount
```

Need something like this code :

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [myDB] WHERE @ID = [ID])
set [count] = [count] + 1 and [Amount] = [Amount] - 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Use simple update query like this:

```
UPDATE myDB
SET [count] = [count] + 1
, [Amount] = [Amount] - 1
WHERE ID = @ID
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6142d/1)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE MST_SPR_donategifts
    SET Gift_Quantity = Gift_Quantity- @Gift_Quantity
    WHERE Gift_Code=@Gift_Code

Comment: Looks like your formatting is a bit odd. It could also do with a bit of explanation, not just code.